# How to write a Bash program that searches through Directories and lists the files that have the largest numbered suffix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a program that will search through a main directories sub-directories and list the files that have the largest number at the end. ex: filename_100.

```
find . -name "*_*" | sort -n | tail
```

Comment: Do you want it to list the file with the largest number at the end for _each_ prefix, or only to find the largest ending number across all prefixes and list files with that ending number?

Comment: Hi David, I want it to find the largest ending number, say 100. Then look at the prefix, filename (example: prob589) to determine if they are part of the same thread and then print all of the files up to the largest number. So it would list prob589_(first instance) to prob589_(last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` sorts starting from the beginning of the string, so you can't use it without first splitting off the leading part of the filename. This loop will do that; it prints out the part of the filename after the `_`, followed by the full filename.

```
for fn in `find . -name '*_*'`; do
    echo "${fn##*_} $fn"
done
```

Then you can pipe the output to `sort` and `tail` to get the largest number, and then to `cut` to pick out only the filename itself.

```
for fn in `find . -name '*_*'`; do
    echo "${fn##*_} $fn"
done | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-
```

Then you'll need to extract the part of the filename before the underscore. This is probably best done by storing the result of the last part in a variable,

```
largest_filename="$(for fn in `find . -name '*_*'`; do
    echo "${fn##*_} $fn"
done | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)"
```

after which you can use bash's suffix removal to strip off the part after the underscore, and then list all files that share that prefix.

```
largest_filename="$(for fn in `find . -name '*_*'`; do
    echo "${fn##*_} $fn"
done | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)"
ls ${largest_filename%_*}_*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
#retrieve largest suffix
find . -name '*_*' | xargs -n 1 basename | awk -F'_' '{print($NF, $0)}' | sort -k1,1 -n -r | awk '{print($1)}' | head -1 > $tmp1
tmp2=$(mktemp)
#retrieve file names containing largest suffix
join -o2.2 -1 1 -2 1  $tmp1 <(find . -name '*_*' | xargs -n 1 basename | awk -F'_' '{print($NF, $0)}' | sort -k1,1 ) > $tmp2
join -o2.1,2.2 -1 1 -2 1 -t"_" $tmp2 <(find . -name '*_*' | xargs -n 1 basename | sort -k1,1 -t"_")
```